# I have 2 select options. How can I make the second select menu options only show up based on what is selected in the first select menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

https://jsfiddle.net/adm0L6x1/

```html
<div class="input-group" style="margin-left: 20px;">

  <select class="form-control" id="asd">
    <option></option>
    <option>BOSTON, MA</option>
    <option>FORT LEE, NJ</option>
    <option>HACKENSACK, NJ</option>
    <option>NEWARK, NJ</option>
    <option>NEY YORK CITY, NY</option>
    <option>NORTH ARLINGTON, NJ</option>
    <option>PHILADELPHIA, PA</option>
    <option>WASHINGTON, D.C</option>
  </select>

  <select class="form-control" id="asd">
    <option></option>
  </select>
</div>
```

So basically I am making a form so the user can choose a destination to go too and from. When I click an option in "From", I only want certain options to show up in "To". For Example, if they choose From:Boston, MA I only want New york city and Washington DC to show up in the too. But if I choose From: NYC I only want Philadelphia to show up in the too. Ive looked at a couple jquery/javascript examples but cant find anything on this exact scenario.

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31948523/set-select-options-dynamically-in-catalog-product-page-in-magento-admin-panel/31949430#31949430

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works nicely. You want to create a config object in javascript that stores the cities and the destinations. Use the config to populate the FROM select. Then use an `eventListener` on the FROM select to get the selected value. Finally clear and populate the TO select using the value (destinations) for the new selection listed in the config.

```
var select1 = document.getElementById('select1');
var select2 = document.getElementById('select2');

// Config
// Key: City
// Value: Array of city destinations
var config = {
  'BOSTON, MA' : [ 'NEY YORK CITY, NY', 'WASHINGTON D.C.' ],
  'FORT LEE, NJ' : [ ],
  'HACKENSACK, NJ' : [],
  'NEWARK, NJ' : [ ],
  'NORTH ARLINGTON, NJ' : [],
  'NEY YORK CITY, NY' : [ 'PHILADELPHIA, PA' ],
  'PHILADELPHIA, PA' : [ ],
  'WASHINGTON D.C.' : [ ]
}

// add item method

var addItemToSelect = function (select, label) {
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.textContent = label;
    option.value = label;
    select.appendChild(option);
}

// populate select 1

for (var city in config) {
  addItemToSelect(select1, city);
}

select1.addEventListener('change', function () {

  // get selection's destinations
  var selection = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
  var destinations = config[selection];

  // clear select 2
  select2.length = 0

  // populate select 2
  addItemToSelect(select2, '');
  for (var key in destinations) {
    addItemToSelect(select2, destinations[key]);
  }

});
```

And the HTML

```
<div class="input-group" style="margin-left: 20px;">

  <div>
    <label>From</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="select1">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div>
    <label>To</label>
    <select class="form-control" id="select2">
      <option></option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/33tcpLon/

Answer (score 0):

First of all you shouldn't use 2 ids with the same name.

Having change the second id to "asd1" for example, you can do this:

```
function foo() {
    var selectedElem = document.getElementById("asd");
    var selectedText = e.options[e.selectedIndex].text;

    var x = document.getElementById("asd1");
    var option = document.createElement("option");
    option.text = "Kiwi";
    x.add(option);
}
```

Sorry, forgot to add the onchange method:

In your first select element:

```
<select class="form-control" id="asd" onchange="foo()">
```

Comment: yeah that was just for some CSS stuff, I am going to change it to class. I will give this a try though. Also, how would I implement this function in the HTML?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by implementing this function in the HTML, but if you want to include this function in the HTML file you must put it in a script tag, like "<script> function foo() ...</script>"

Comment: ahh. the onchange was what I was asking about